# Type of route name, route params in React Navigation Typescript

Tags: react-native, react-typescript, react-navigation-v6

I am using ReactNavigation v6 along with typescript

I have created a helper functions as

```
export function navigate(routeName, routeParams) {
  navigationRef.current?.navigate(routeName, routeParams);
}
```

**What type should I specify for routeName & routeParams such that it type checks these params correctly?**

I have the following types for my StackNavigator

```
export type StackNavigator = {
  Welcome: undefined;
  Username: undefined;
  Password: undefined;
  ForgotPassword: {id: number};
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **routeName** parameter can be typed using the following type

```
type Routes = keyof StackNavigator
```

But the **routeParams** will be dynamic. i.e. **routeParams** will change as per **routeName**

It can be

```
{id: number} or undefined
```

So to compute the 2nd parameter on basis of value of 1st parameter we can do the following

```
type NavigationArgs = {
  [Route in keyof StackNavigator]: [
    routeName: Route,
    routeParams?: StackNavigator[Route],
  ];
}[keyof StackNavigator];

export function navigate(...args: NavigationArgs) {
  const [routeName, routeParams] = args;
  navigationRef.current?.navigate(routeName, routeParams);
}
```

This will ensure strict type checking